# commons beanutils alternative

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

I am looking for a commons beanutils alternative.
The reason is that beanutils relies on commons-logging which is conflicting with existing libraries I am using.

I would like a small self-contained alternative which will cause no/minimal conflicts.

The main functionality I am after is nested property retrieval.

Thanks in advance,
Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up writing my own mini beanutils to get around this dependency and removed commons-beanutils completely.

The SLF4J did not end up helping since it broke some other dependencies (damn you weblogic!).

My own implementation is probably slower since the commons-beanutils appears to cache some fetches to remove some reflective calls.

Msg me if your interested in getting the source code of my implementation.

Comment: "My own implementation is probably slower since the commons-beanutils " Commons-beanutils is open-source. Maybe you just download the source, and rip out the calls to commons logging. OTOH, your code is probably not slower to a degree that makes any difference anyway.

Comment: I tried that but it ended up pulling in digest and other things as well. Just got a little bit too tedious and my solution was very small and easy anyway.

Answer (score 6):

While property handling is not the main focus of [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes), it can be used for that, as per [this article](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/02/entry_440.html).

The basic idea is that you can not only read/write JSON to/from POJOs, but also do compatible conversions: including that of "serializing" a POJO as a Java Map. Since you can go back and forth between representations you basically get a bean introspector for free.

Jackson has no external dependencies, but you need both core (streaming api, impls) and mapper jars (data binding).

Answer (score 6):

[Jodd](https://jodd.org/) has very good collection of libraries, See if [Jodd BeanUtil](https://util.jodd.org/beanutil/beanutil) helps.

Comment: It's perfect 'small self-contained alternative which will cause no/minimal conflicts' :)

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to resolve the conflict with commons-logging by using the alternate commons-logging [bridge implementation provided by SFL4j](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html).

> Often times, replacing commons-logging.jar with jcl-over-slf4j.jar will immediately and permanently solve class loader issues related to commons logging.

Comment: I will give this a go first and let you know

Comment: Did not help, just caused more dependency problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Maven, you can exclude the commons-logging dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.3</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I've done the same with Spring, which also requires commons-logging.  In fact Spring themselves [taught me how to exclude it](http://blog.springsource.org/2009/12/04/logging-dependencies-in-spring/).  As far as I can tell, I now have a commons-logging-free environment.

**Update**:  for something like SLF4J / Logback, you may also need this in your config file:

```
<logger name="org.apache.commons" level="OFF" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A valid alternative with no conflicts with other libraries is [BULL](https://github.com/HotelsDotCom/bull), you can find a guide on how to use it on [DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-transform-any-type-of-java-bean-with-one-li). It offers the possibility to also perform object transformation while coping.